# Unusual error in mysql "delete" query

Tags: mysql, bash, sql-delete

I have the following mysql code which I run in a shell script:

```
mysql  -u "$DB_USER" -p"$DB_PASSWD" "$DB_SOURCE" << MYSQLEOF

DELETE FROM list_subscriber_events WHERE subscriberid IN
(SELECT subscriberid FROM
(SELECT subscriberid FROM `list_subscriber_events` WHERE subscriberid NOT IN
(SELECT subscriberid FROM list_subscribers)) AS c);

MYSQLEOF
```

When running the delete query from the command line in mysql I have no problems - it runs ok.

However when running it in the bash script I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE subscriberid NOT IN
(SELECT subscriberid FROM list_subscribers)) AS c)' at line 3
ssh exited with exit code 1
```

I've spent hours trying all sorts of variations - I can't seem to resolve it. Any help would be appreciated - I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: Well you do seem to have single comment marks on your second SELECT subscriberid FROM statement), does that affect anything?

Comment: I've retried it and that's solved it - thank you.

I'm sure I took them off and tested it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the backtick characters

```
   FROM `list_subscriber_events` WHERE
        ^                      ^
```

In the context of a shell command line, those backticks indicate something that needs to be run, and the return from that is substituted.

I suspect that the shell is interpreting those backticks, and attempting to execute `list_subscriber_events`, which is likely returning an error. The result is that this gets replaced with an empty string...  the resulting statement is

```
 ... FROM WHERE ...
```

If you have to include backticks, likely preceding the backtick with a backslash character will escape it.

**FOLLOWUP**

On a totally different note, it seems like you have more inline views that are necessary. And there's a potential "gotcha" with the `NOT IN`, if the subquery returns a NULL value. (Maybe you have a guarantee that `subscriberid` is NOT NULL in `list_subscribers`. Or, maybe you do want the behavior we get when that subquery returns a NULL value.)

Seems like a much simpler query, using an anti-join pattern would accomplish the result you seem to be after...  to remove the rows from `list_subscriber_events` where the `subscriberid` value does not appear in `list_subscribers`

```
  DELETE e.*
    FROM list_subscriber_events e
    LEFT
    JOIN list_subscribers l
      ON l.subscriberid = d.subscriberid
   WHERE l.subscriberid IS NULL
```